# How to get variable branch in C++ with concert CPLEX

Tags: visual-studio, cplex

I used NodeCallback to get variable branch with this code:

```
ILONODECALLBACK0(myVB){
for (int i = 0; i < getNnodes(); i++) {
cout << "BranhVariable_" << getBranchVar(i) << endl;
}
}
```

And the output is:
[image]

I can't verify the output details. I expect one variable selected for branching at each node but it shows more than one variable. 
Also after twenty nodes I got error 1006.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems you are going with the default node display frequency? That shows a log line only every N nodes (and between two log lines there may be more than one branch). So you may have to set the MIPDisplay parameter to 1.

Also, the node callback is invoked whenever a node has to be selected (so more or less at each not in the tree). But then it always prints the branch variable for **every** open node. If you want to see the branching variable for the node about to be selected then print it only for the first node (the node that CPLEX would choose is at index 0, the order of the rest of the node list is unspecified).

Comment: Thank you dear Daniel for answering. I set MIPDisplay parameter to 5. I don’t know I got your mean right or not. Your mean is for example at node20  twenty one nodes are open for processing and at this selected node(node20) the first node which is node24 is selected for branching, is it true? If yes, how can I fixed the error 1006 to run for the rest of the nodes? because it has stopped the running of the program.

Comment: About the error 1006: You first have to figure out what exactly this error is to know what you are doing wrong. Wrap you whole callback code into a `try { ... } catch (IloException &e) { std::cout << "EXCEPTION: " << e << std::endl; throw; }` and check what the error is and which statement triggers that error.

Comment: Thank you.I found my problem. as it is written in IBM documentation for NodeCallback, I have to use getNremainingNodes() instead of getNnodes() in the loop.